# GCC - Signed Long within limits causes warning during compilation

Tags: c, gcc

In my limits.h, the limit of a signed long is given as - define LONG_MAX     2147483647L

However, the following line of code causes a warning for "integer overflow in expression"
But the program runs file and produces the expected value.

```
long universe_of_defects = 1L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 2L - 1L;
printf("The entire universe has %ld bugs.\n", universe_of_defects);
```

The value printed is - 2147483647

So what is the cause of this warning and how it can be fixed?
I have GCC - gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Note - the code is from "Learn C the hard way"

Comment: thats because you have mentioned L for long and didnt put parentheses (1*1024*1024*1024*2) - 1 should solve your issue

Comment: @KinjalPatel: I'm not sure parentheses will help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part of that calculation overflows:

```
    1L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 2L  -  1L
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  2,147,483,648  >  2,147,483,647    It's too late!
//  Overflow occurs                    previous value is overflowed
```

Try

```
long universe_of_defects = 1LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 - 1;
```

that `LL` promotes the value to `long long` type, then after `-1` it can fit to a `long` again.

Answer (score 2):

Because one of the intermediate results overflows, which technically leads to undefined behaviour.

To avoid this, perhaps do the calculation in a type that can hold the intermediate results, e.g. an unsigned long (`UL`) or a long long (`LL`).

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: it may be implementation-defined, I don't have the standard in front of me. Either way, it's not great!

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: definitely undefined, yes.